# how to connect to mysql using c# string connection

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database using c# and Entity Framework. Im working on a code that isnt mine and Im new to c#. I have the MySql.Data and MySql.Data.EntityFramework both in 8.0.32 version. I have permission to connect to the database and I was succesfully connected to it through other softwares.
my connection string currently looks like this:

```
<add name="defaultDb" connectionString="metadata=res://*/VitoriasModel.csdl|res://*/VitoriasModel.ssdl|res://*/VitoriasModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;SERVER=remoteconnection(I cant put the server number here);DATABASE=dbname;UID=username;PASSWORD=password &quot;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

> and when i run it it gives me this error: option not supported
> "metadata"

I have tried taking the metadata out, it would look something like this:

```
 <add name="defaultDb" connectionString="SERVER=remoteconnection(I cant put the server number here);DATABASE=dbname;UID=username;PASSWORD=password;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`
```

but it returns me an exception:

> Entity Framework UnintentionalCodeFirstException

and apparently this is solved by adding a metadata with the edmx path, that is not working for me!

Im using EF and dbcontext to make the connection to the database

```
public partial class vitoriasExample : DbContext
    {
        public vitoriasExample()
            : base("name=defaultDb")
        {
        }
```

Comment: [MySQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: I would suggest you use Pomelo instead official MySQL library.